# Postgres get out enough view information to reproduce it

Tags: postgresql

Basically - I want to get out enough information from postgres to reproduce a view - I know I can do a

```sql
select * from pg_get_viewdef('my_view')
```

which gets me the select statement, but not the *create* part of it - which could be a normal view or a materialized view - and then there could grants and for a materialized view indexes.

I know I can work through all of that myself, but I'll probably get it wrong or miss something - is there an easier way in postgres?   ie something that I can get out that gives me the complete ddl for reconstructing the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get the `CREATE VIEW` statement and all `GRANT`s is to run `pg_dump`:

```sh
pg_dump -t viewschema.viewname dbname
```

If you cannot use that, collecting the information is more difficult:

- I recommend that you use the views `pg_views` and `pg_matviews`. They contain a column `definition` which contains the result of `pg_get_viewdef`. Just prepend `CREATE VIEW`  or `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` for the complete statement.
- Permissions for views can be conveniently got from `information_schema.table_privileges`, but this view does not contain materialized views.

  To get permissions directly from the metadata, you can use:

  ```
  SELECT c.oid::regclass AS table_or_view
         p.grantor::regrole,
         p.grantee::regrole,
         p.privilege_type,
         p.is_grantable
  FROM pg_class AS c
     CROSS JOIN LATERAL aclexplode(c.relacl) AS p
  WHERE c.relname = 'v';
  ```

  Here, a `-` as `grantee` means `PUBLIC`.

Comment: unfortunately I am in a constrained corporate have no access to the db server or the ability to install postgres tools - so I'm limited to what I can do with a connection to the database - ie I need something I can do from _inside_ the database :(

Comment: I have added some hints.

Comment: "unfortunately I am in a constrained corporate ...". Then talk to your DBA. If you can make a business case, they will give it to you. The definition and if  you show sufficient need then also the necessary access. That is there job, let them do it.